# Trying to setPage() from a HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, classcastexception, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to get the page from a HttpsURLConnection to setPage() on a component.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

That's an error I get.

Any fixes?

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.lalala.tk/website.html");
HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that there's no way to tell you where you're doing the wrong thing ... the error is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong. You can't magically cast something to something that it isn't

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the wrong class. I bet somewhere in your code there is

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
```

But instead, it should be

```
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;
```

Try to replace the imports and I am sure it will work out.

Comment: Erm, how would that cause a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: The website is using cloudflare and it tells me to use HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: @KeirDavis Have you changed the `import`?

Comment: No, I want a HttpsURLConnection, not HttpURLConnection.